# QML ListView sections not showing

Tags: qt, listview, qml

I am trying to display a list of contacts in a ListView in QML. The list comes from the c++ side of my app and the contents are displaying just fine.

Now I want to be able to add sections from the name, but it doesn't work as I want.

What is weird is that the following code does work and shows the sections I want :

Working solution :

```
main.cpp :
    QList<QObject*> contactList;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("contactsModel", QVariant::fromValue(contactList));

contoller.cpp :
    ...
    // Call setContextProperty every time the list is updated
    m_qmlEngine->setContextProperty("contactsModel", QVariant::fromValue(m_currentUser->contactListObjects()));
    ...

qml file :
    ListView {
        id: contactListView
        model: contactsModel

        section {
            property: "name"
            criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
            delegate: Rectangle {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the way that i find more elegant only shows the data from the model, not the section headers :

```
main.cpp :
    Controller ctrl(engine.rootContext());
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Controller", &ctrl);

contoller.h :

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> contactListModel READ contactListModel NOTIFY contactListModelChanged)
...
};

qml file :
    ListView {
        id: contactListView
        model: Controller.contactListModel

        section {
            property: "name"
            criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
            delegate: Rectangle {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

I find the second method more elegant because the data will be updated automatically from the signal that is emitted, whereas the first solution means I need to call the setContextProperty method each time.

I found a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68770385/qml-listview-sections-cannot-access-model-property-in-a-dynamically-created-c), but unfortunately there are no answers.

What difference am I missing between the 2 solutions ?

Comment: You should not need to call setContextProperty more than once. Show how you are updating your model. Most likely you are missing beginResetModel/endResetModel.

Comment: Actually i was going off the Qt documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model where it states "Note: There is no way for the view to know that the contents of a QList has changed. If the QList changes, it is necessary to reset the model by calling QQmlContext::setContextProperty() again."

Comment: I was assuming your model was a QAbstractListModel.

Comment: However, after trying to update the model from the c++ side, the ListView isn't updated in either case (notify signal or calling the setContextProperty again). I have to destroy the window containing the ListView and open it again for the new data to be added

Comment: Please provide a [mre].